# How to use this in a constructor with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

What is a good approach to giving `this` a type annotation in a constructor?

```
function Client(options: ClientOptions) {
    const defaultOptions = { 
        host: 'ws://127.0.0.1',
        port:  8080,
        logger: function() {
            const prefix = "LOG:";
            console.log.call(null, prefix, ...Array.from(arguments))
        },
        maxTime: 30000, 
        startFromTransactionId: 1
    };

    Object.assign(this, { ...defaultOptions, ...options });

    this.transactionsCounter = 0;
    this.requestCallbacks  {};
    this.socket = null;
}
```

> [ts] 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
>   annotation.

**Elaboration**

My editor shows me red squiggly lines beneath each use of the `this` keyword in this constructor. I get a `[ts]` warning that this does not have any type annotation.

How should I go about adding type annotation to `this`?

Comment: Not clear with your question Can you little bit elaborate it ?

Comment: @CodeChanger: Thanks for trying to help. Let me know if my elaboration still is not clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `this` can be defined [as a fake parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters), in first position:

```
function Client(this: any, options: ClientOptions) {
    // ...
}
```

Or, this kind of error can be disabled by setting the compiler option `--noImplicitThis` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using typescript you could use Class instead of this approach.
There you wont have any errors with using this.xxx
And as a bonus you will get type hinting when using the class